# error during Upload new APK to google play store for Production

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I have experienced a problem when I upload my apk to the Play store.
[image]

I am using google play service library version 19 for wearable support. I got this error message during publishing process.

Comment: your minSdk version is 8 .... you need to change with 9

Comment: There is any solutions without changing min sdk version ?

Comment: change the lower version google_play_services lib

Answer (score 1):

Since [Google Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html):

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

Therefore any Google Play Services you are using will only work on API level 9 (2.3 Gingerbread) or higher devices. As per the suggestion, you should consider raising your minimum API level to 9 to match Google Play Services. As of [the August 2014 Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), Android 2.3+ accounts for 99.3% of devices worldwide.

Comment: And I assume you actually have a large percentage of users on <v9? If so, you can certainly guard every Google Play Services call with [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()]( http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) calls, but you may find it more work than it is worth to support those users

Comment: But we got this issue during uploading the apk. after 99% we got this warning. So how we can use this checking?? how we get through the publishing process?

Comment: From the screenshot you posted it says it is a warning and you are 'discouraged' from keeping the min SDK lower than 9 (obviously as every method call into Google Play Services will crash those older devices). If it is not in fact a warning but a blocking error then you don't really have a choice. Note that if you publish a new min SDK, users on older versions will still be able to download and install the latest version compatible with their phone (effectively freezing them on the last version). You may want to publish one last bug fix release for <9 users and then publish the new 9+ version.

Comment: So you suggesting a multiple apk , one for older device (< api level9) and one for higer devices (> api level 9)

Comment: In a way: when you stop supporting an older API level, users can still download the last version that was compatible with their API level (i.e., you publish 3.0 min API 7, then 4.0 is min API 9 - a user with API 8 will still get version 3.0 if they download your app a year later). In essence, you get multiple APK for free when you retire API level support. Mentioning a final bug fix release is only because it is of course more tricky to simultaneously support multiple APKs - Android 2.1 and 2.2 cannot be that worthwhile if Google (and Google Play Services) and Facebook no longer support it.

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file, you should have something like this:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Go and check for the value in there to make sure what version of google play service you are using.